# Measure application performance on ARM development board

Tags: performance, embedded, arm, embedded-linux, ubuntu-11.10

I have a C++ application and i want to measure its performance on ARM board. The board is running ubuntu.

Currently i am considering valgrind and gprof to measure the performance.

What tools/techniques should i use to measure the performance?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are the biggies I ran across last time I had to do this:

- [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) (only supported on cortex ARM processors.. boo)
- mprof (not so hot with threads?)
- gprof (not so hot with threads?)
- [oprofile](http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/news/) (requires kernel mods, but most modern kernels have it. I've used this under ARM.
- [systemtap](http://sourceware.org/systemtap/) (recently ported to arm, looks awesome - like dtrace for Linux)
- strace and ltrace can actually be useful sometimes, although very high-level
- iostat et all as well if you want to kick it old school.
- Fair amount of information in /proc/ and /sys if you dig
- [ioapps](http://code.google.com/p/ioapps/) - IO tracing
- lsof is useful for tracking stuck sockets and file handles
- systat
- pmap
- iptraf
- tcpdump
- [perftools](http://code.google.com/p/google-perftools/) - CPU and memory profiling
- [bootchart](http://www.bootchart.org/)
- QEMU can host ARM kernels / binaries, and can be instrumented from outside. It's proven useful to me a couple times.
- Manual instrumentation using the gcc hooks

  `void __cyg_profile_func_enter (void *, void *) __attribute__((no_instrument_function));`
  `void __cyg_profile_func_exit (void *, void *) __attribute__((no_instrument_function));`

Comment: Thanks. Any idea about how much effort is required for systemtap to setup it for performance measuring? As you have used oprofile, what you say should i consider it?

Comment: I've only read about system tap, but I liked what I read. oprofile was a bit heavyweight and cryptic, but that was 3 years ago. If I had to go do this task again, if systemtap kernel settings are available I'd start going down that path first.